# How to make an app for a Wordpress Blog?

Tags: iphone, wordpress, rss, xml-rpc

I want to make an iPhone OS app for a Wordpress blog, and I'm unable to figure a way to grab the data from the blog.

- The XML-RPC doesn't seem to have an anonymous read-only mode
- The RSS feed has truncated posts

So, if anyone managed to make it, please help me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the RSS is truncated if it is configured to be so, you can publish the entire blogpost in wordpress, cfr. "settings -> reading settings -> For each article in a feed, show (full text/ summary)"

Answer (score 0):

The newsfeed may contain the full post. This is an option for the blog owner (option: `'rss_use_excerpt' = 0`).